# Haskell and java.awt.Robot

Tags: haskell

I'm interested in writing a program that takes control of keyboard and mouse in much the same way that one can with java.awt.Robot. I assume of course that there's no way to do this with standard libraries. Does anyone know of a good library I can connect to by means of FFI to achieve something like this?

Comment: My goal here is to write a Haskell program.

Comment: I like how someone asks how to interface java with haskell and the first comments are just asking why not use java... Anyway, I think lambada might be what you are looking for.

Comment: To be more precise, I'm not necessarily interested in interfacing Haskell with Java. I'd just like java.awt.Robot-like functionality in whichever way is the most direct way to get it. I can't imagine that there isn't some alternative to firing up a JVM and working through a JNI interface just to take control of the keyboard.

Comment: Not that it's relevant, but the reason I'd like to do this is I'm working on some ideas for an accessibility application that allows programmers with RSIs to code by voice.

Comment: @monadic We're not asking why he can't use Java, we're trying to get a clearer description by prodding for more details. Don't always assume you know exactly what everyone is thinking. The OP obviously wants something like `Robot` but doesn't say how close it can be. Can it run in the JVM? Does it need to be cross-platform?

Comment: @Ara Thanks for the clarification, that's what I meant by the original question. I know of course that it's a Java library but you should always clarify why you are looking for an alternative to something otherwise we can't give you good recommendations.

Comment: @Abdullah From the other person - "Why can't you use Java? – hammar 19 hours ago" If thats not asking why he can't use Java, I don't know what is :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any relevant experience, sorry. My first thought would be to look at other UI libraries, such as GTK,

- http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/GdkDisplay.html#gdk-display-warp-pointer

It looks like this may be already exported to Haskell via gtk2hs. If you know how to use the C foreign function interface, the XTest extension library seems to have what you want. ( http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libXtst/xtestlib.html ).

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this in Windows take a look at [Win32::GuiTest](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/Win32-GuiTest/README.html). In X11 you can use [X11::GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/~ctrondlp/X11-GUITest-0.25/GUITest.pm). Both are Perl wrappers over native system calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you use X11, you can use either [**XTest**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xtest) or the higher level [**Robot**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/robot).

Here's an example of XTest:

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Monad (forever)
import Graphics.X11.Xlib
import Graphics.X11.XTest

main = withDisplay "" $ \dpy -> forever $ do
    sendKey dpy [] xK_a
    threadDelay (500 * 1000)
```

and here's an example of Robot:

```
import Control.Monad (forever)
import Test.Robot

main = runRobot . forever $ do
    tap _A
    sleep 0.5
```